# Team Foundation Server - Sql Server Version Management

Tags: sql-server, version-control, tfs

Does TFS offer any enhanced ways of storing changes made to a sql server database other than using it to version text files of sql statements executed on the database?

Or is the functionality I'm looking for only available in 3rd party tools like Red Gate's tools or Quest's Change Director?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is offered by Visual Studio Database Edition.

Comment: I had no idea that's exactly what the database edition of visual studio offer, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.